# Python. MemoryError

Tags: python, алгоритм, outofmemoryerror

Всем привет. Возникла такая проблема.
Решил я кое-какую задачу. Решение правильно для небольшого диапозона.
Но когда ввод забольшой, то возникает ошибка пам'яти. Вот мой код.
Диапозон 1 <= n <= 10^18
Пожалуйста подскажите что делать

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

def tidy_num():
   n = int(raw_input())

   last = 0

   for i in range(1, n+1):
       if i >= 0 and i <= 9:
           last = i
       else:
           number = str(i)
           cur = 0
           numC = 0
           for j in number:
               if int(j) >= cur:
                   numC = numC + 1
                   cur = int(j)
           if numC == len(number):
               last = i
   return last

for case in xrange(input()):
    print 'Case #%d: %s' % (case+1, tidy_num())
```

> Програма должна вывести последее правильное число. Правильное число -
>   число в котором каждая следующая цифра >= предыдущей

Comment: Круто. Снизу Вы знаете про функцию xrange, а сверху нет.

Comment: Я пробовал, но не помогло

Comment: А что делает этот код ? За 10 минут я не понял ничего. Пока просто сходу могу сказать, что начав просмотр с конца диапазона Вы решите задачу за пару итераций, а не часы работы ЦП.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу @ReinRaus - объясните что вы хотите сделать и было бы неплохо привести небольшой пример входных данных и результат...

Comment: Програма должна вывести последее правильное число. Правильное число - чсло в котором каждая следующая цифра >= предыдущей

Comment: вход - количество тесткейсов. далее вводим число и получим последнее правильное. например 1 тесткейс. 132 ---> 129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
def tidy_num2(n):
    lst = str(n)
    if len(lst) == 1 or sorted(lst) == list(lst):
        return n
    x = -1
    # x - порядковый номер последней "неправильной" цифры с конца 
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i] > lst[i+1]:
            x = len(lst) - i - 1
            break
    #print(i, x)
    # увеличиваем порядок для чисел вида: 12220
    while i >= 1:
        if lst[i-1] == lst[i]:
            x += 1
        else:
            break
        i -= 1
    return n if x < 0 else n//10**x * 10**x - 1
```

Примеры:

```
In [444]: %timeit tidy_num2(10**18)
The slowest run took 4.89 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.58 µs per loop

In [445]: %timeit tidy_num2(11111111111111111111110)
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.1 µs per loop

In [446]: tidy_num2(11111111111111111111110)
Out[446]: 9999999999999999999999

In [447]: tidy_num2(123123)
Out[447]: 122999

In [448]: tidy_num2(1234)
Out[448]: 1234

In [449]: tidy_num2(12340)
Out[449]: 12339

In [450]: tidy_num(12340)
Out[450]: 12339
```

**Предыдущий ответ:**

Я бы сделал так:

```
def tidy_num2(n):
    lst = str(n)
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return n
    x = -1
    # x - порядковый номер последней "неправильной" цифры с конца 
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i] > lst[i+1]:
            x = len(lst) - i - 1
            break
    return n if x < 0 else n//10**x * 10**x - 1
```

Comment: Работает. Но не правильно на большом вводе. Например ввод 111111111111111110 ---> 111111111111111109,
а должно ---> 99999999999999999

Comment: @Dmytro, для какого числа работает неправильно?

Comment: например 111111111111111110

Comment: какое число должна возвращать функция для входного числа `110`?

Comment: должно       110 ---> 99

Comment: @Dmytro, тогда буду дальше думать... ;-) Можно конечно рекурсивно  функцию `tidy_num2()` вызывать, но это не красиво ...

Comment: странно но у меня зацикливание получилось

Comment: @Dmytro, сейчас вроде бы правильно должно работать

Comment: Все отлично. Огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: @Dmytro, рад помочь (тем более когда задача интересная ;)

Answer (score 0):

хз, что делает Ваш код, но начав перебор с конца Вы решите задачу за пару итераций:

```
import sys

def tidy_num():
   n = int(input())

   last = 0

   for i in range(n, 0, -1):
       if i >= 0 and i <= 9:
           last = i
       else:
           number = str(i)
           cur = 0
           numC = 0
           for j in number:
               if int(j) >= cur:
                   numC = numC + 1
                   cur = int(j)
           if numC == len(number):
               return i

for case in range(int(input())):
    print ('Case #%d: %s' % (case+1, tidy_num()) )
```

Код на Python3, а не Python2, который Вы используете.

Comment: Пробовал и так. Но к сожелению когда ввожу например 1000000000000000000, програма не работает(

Comment: `1 
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 
Case #1: 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999` работает же...